# I am a three-dimensional grid

Tags: riddle

I am a three-dimensional grid.
I keep out intruders.
I also prevent disease.
I travel often to remote and rugged locations.

difficulty level: easy (1/5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A mosquito net. It is a fabric woven to make tiny squares (3D grid) to keep out mosquitos (the intruders), thereby preventing diseases like malaria. It is brought camping or hiking (remote and rugged locations).

Comment: Bravo! +1 to you.